# How can i debug a native function in hadoop source code?

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, java-native-interface

I am trying to understand the hadoop source code by debugging it using eclipse.
while I debug it, I met a native function named start0() here :
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/lang/Thread.java#Thread.start0%28%29

can I debug it using eclipse"or using any external tool" or at least can I read the source code for this function?
Hadoop is an open source so it supposed I can access and read the code for all functions in it, but I don't know how.

```
Note: my hadoop version : 1.2.1
```

---

Edit : 
I read about native function and from what I read, the class that contain the native function should contain something like that :

```
`// load DLL that contains static method
static {
System.loadLibrary("NativeDemo");
}`
```

but the thread class in hadoop contains this :
    `/* Make sure registerNatives is the first thing <clinit> does. */
    134     private static native void More ...registerNatives();
    135     static {
    136         registerNatives();
    137     }`

So How can I know the name of library that start0() function linked to ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally get that start0() function is a part from java code not a part of hadoop code, so it is just do/create a new thread to run the job on it and for hadoop developing we just need to know that :
**Thread.start0 eventually creates a new operating system thread, and calls Thread.run() in that new thread.**
also the run function that is called after creating the new thread is here:
http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.ning/metrics.collector/1.2.1/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/LocalJobRunner.java#LocalJobRunner.Job.run%28%29

Answer (score 0):

You can always get the source code. Sample configuration file, for your version is [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.ning/metrics.collector/1.2.1/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.java)

Comment: where is the source code for the function start0() in the config file ?

Comment: The given link is in general for Hadoop related source code. The point which you were referring above is Thread.start() which would be invoked in general for a new process. So you wont find start() in config